# How can I share file between PC and cloud hosted VM?

Tags: azure, powershell, cmd, cloud, virtual-machine

I've been trying to send an email with PowerShell.

I have a VM hosted on azure from which I attempted to print a document using Microsoft print to pdf, I later realized that the files are saved to a different instance I can't directly access and the only option I have is to launch a command prompt from the file path from which I'm running PS script.

Is there any other way I can get out my docs?

```
$Username ="xxxxx@azure.com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $Password
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$EmailFrom = "from@mail.com"
$EmailTo = "to@mail.com"
$Subject = "email from ps test"
$Body = "Test email sent successfully"

Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $SMTPServer -Credential $credential -Usessl -Port 465 -from $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -subject $Subject -Body $Body
```

Comment: Why are you launching a Command Prompt as opposed to a Windows PowerShell window, when you're dealing with a PowerShell script. Regardless of that, this site helps to to fix a reproducible issue with your programming code. Without code, it is unlikely that this site can assist you, because your problem seems to be methodology, not a code related.

Comment: Thank you so much @Compo, I only have access to the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an Azure Storage Account and use Azure File Share to share files between your local environment and your Azure Virtual Machine.

here's a step by step showing how to connect Azure File Share to your local environment:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#mount-the-azure-file-share

PS: Connect to the VM an run the same command